# How to prevent recaptcha__en.js to load multiple times?

Tags: javascript, loading, recaptcha

I have noticed that reCAPTCHA is loading four times the same script recaptcha__en.js from the gstatic.com server on my page containing a basic contact form. How can I limit it to only one load of the file to lighten the page?

preview: https://ibb.co/gR5BpH

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Did this ever get resolved?